# Call other component's method

Tags: reactjs, components

I have this little component:

```
import React from 'react';

const Footer = (props) => {
    return (
    <footer className="top">
      <p>{props.items} items in your menu</p>
    </footer>
  )
}

const updateItems = (n) => {
    this.props.items = this.props.items + n;
};

Footer.propTypes = {
  items: React.PropTypes.string.isRequired
};

export default Footer;
```

And from the main component:

```
// All irrelevant imports
import Footer from './Footer';

class App extends React.Component {
   // All the irrelevant vars and methods

   removeFish = (key) => {
        const fishes = {...this.state.fishes};
        fishes[key] = null;
        this.setState({ fishes });
        Footer.updateItems(-1); // <-- This is not updating the items count in the footer component
    };
}
```

My Footer.updateItems doesn't seem to update the value, even that the console fires no errors and the app complies,

Which would be the correct way?

Comment: `updateItems` should be a method of  the `Footer` component and update a value in the state of Footer, not a props.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Firstly** updateItems is not a function of Footer component

**Secondly,** you should not change the props directly, you need to change your structuring and handling the updates in the `App` component and let the `Footer` be pure as it is a stateless component

```
import React from 'react';

const Footer = (props) => {
    return (
    <footer className="top">
      <p>{props.items} items in your menu</p>
    </footer>
  )
}

Footer.propTypes = {
  items: React.PropTypes.string.isRequired
};

export default Footer;
```

**App**

```
// All irrelevant imports
import Footer from './Footer';

class App extends React.Component {
   // All the irrelevant vars and methods

   removeFish = (key) => {
        const fishes = {...this.state.fishes};
        fishes[key] = null;
        this.setState({ fishes });

        this.updateItems(-1); 
    };
    updateItems = (n) => {
        this.setState((prevState) => ({items: prevState.items + n}))
     };
    render(){
         return (
               <Footer items={this.state.items}/>
         )
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry couldn't test before, the thing is that I get this error `warning.js:35 Warning: Failed prop type: Required prop items was not specified in Footer.    in Footer (at App.js:129)    in App (created by Match)..` in the console.. Any idea why?

Comment: you need to initialise items as a string in App component